# c# itext7 - Tesseract failed - Visual c++ 2015 Redistributable

Tags: c#, itext7

Starting my application directly out of VS 2019 everything works fine, but after publishing, my

```
OcrPdfCreator.CreatePdfA(imageList, writer, GetRgbPdfOutputIntent())
```

throws the following exception:
"Tesseract failed. Please ensure you have at least Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable installed".

I've installed the VC_redist.x86.exe and VC_redist.x64.exe, but It does not work.

Comment: u see the pack in the installed programs? maybe you have more then one?

Comment: the only ones 1 have is: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (for x86,x64 and arm) version 14.28.29914.

Comment: you trying to run on the same machine, prior to the publish it's working and after publish it's not? also what you mean by publish ?

Comment: I mean, if I run my Unit-Tests for example in Visual Studio it works fine. With publishing I mean rightclick on my project and publish - to create the .exe file for installing the application on the machine (or an other machine). Then (after installing and calling the service) I get this error - it seems that somehow maybe some libs or paths are not correct for itext after that - I'm not sure what I can do to avoid the problem with the Redistributable error.

Comment: I found that https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfOCR/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_pdfocr_1_1_tesseract4_1_1_tesseract4_ocr_exception.html maybe i need to set the path to tesseract somewhere

Comment: you can try to put all your libs and dlls next to the exe. so the program will find them and for sure and see if thats the issue.

Comment: Also you can use "Dependency Walker" and identify what can't be loaded. (you will see alot ot OS related try to find the relevant for tess)

Comment: "Please ensure you have at least Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable installed" hints to only one of the most popular issues, however this exception can happen because of different reasons.

Could you also check if there's an InnerException in the exception that you get?

Comment: Okay thanks I found the problem but I need help how to fix it correctly. After building the project in Visual Studio - in the bin/debug folders there are 2 folder x86 and x64 with the files liblept1760.dll and libtesseract400.dll in it. When I copy these folders to the directory with the .exe file it works. But I don't want to copy these files manually from the bin/debug folder to the published directory - can I somehow configure that these 2 folders with the libraries are created also when I publish/release the program? Thanks so far.

Comment: @ms88-aut could you attach your sample minimal project file to reproduce the problem? Unfortunately, the fix is very VS/MsBuild and project-dependent